# Non-Blocking File IO in Java

Tags: java, nio, named-pipes, nonblocking

I want to write to a named pipe (already created) without blocking on the reader. My reader is another application that may go down. If the reader does go down, I want the writer application to keep writing to that named pipe. Something like a this in Java

```
fopen(fPath, O_NONBLOCK)
```

So that when the reader comes up, it may resume from where it failed.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that with a pipe. I believe that the pipe is toast if either the reader or writer is closed. This is a quote from the Javadoc for PipedOutputStream: "The pipe is said to be broken if a thread that was reading data bytes from the connected piped input stream is no longer alive". I don't think a broken pipe can be fixed.

Comment: @Jim Tough he is talking about a named pipe(http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156). Not the PipedOutputStream from Java SDK.

Comment: Not an answer which you can accept?

Comment: Do you genuinely mean a UNIX named pipe? As in created with mkfifo?

Answer (score 8):

First I try to answer your questions. Next I will try to show you a code snippet I created that solves your problem using blocking IO.

### Your questions

> I want to write to a named pipe
>   (already created) without blocking on
>   the reader

You don't need non blocking IO to solve your problem. I think it can not even help you solve your problem. Blocking IO will also run good(maybe even better then non blocking IO because of the low concurrency). A plus is blocking IO is easier to program. Your reader can/should stay blocking.

> My reader is another application that
>   may go down. If the reader does go
>   down, I want the writer application to
>   neep writing to the named pipe. So that when the reader comes up, it may resume from where it failed.

just put the messages inside a blocking queue. Next write to the named pipe **only** when the reader is reading from it(happens automatically because of blocking IO). No need for non-blocking file IO when you use a blocking queue. The data is asynchronous delivered from the blocking queue when a reader is reading, which will sent your data from your writer to the reader.

> Something like a fopen(fPath,
>   O_NONBLOCK) in Java

You don't need non-blocking IO on the reader and even if you used it. just use blocking IO.

### CODE SNIPPET

A created a little snippet which I believe demonstrates what your needs.

**Components:**

- **Writer.java**: reads lines from console as an example. When you start program enter text followed by enter which will sent it to your named pipe. The writer will resume writing if necessary.
- **Reader.java**: reads lines written from your named pipe(Writer.java).
- **Named pipe**: I assume you have created a pipe named "pipe" in the same directory.

**Writer.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingDeque;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Writer {
    private final BlockingDeque<StringBuffer> queue;
    private final String filename;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Console console = System.console();
        final Writer writer = new Writer("pipe");

        writer.init();

        while(true) {
            String readLine = console.readLine();
            writer.write(new StringBuffer(readLine));
        }
    }

    public Writer(final String filename){
        this.queue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<StringBuffer>();
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public void write(StringBuffer buf) {
        queue.add(buf);
    }

    public void init() {
        ExecutorService single = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    PrintWriter w = null;
                    try {
                        String toString = queue.take().toString();
                        w = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename)), true);
                        w.println(toString);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Writer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        single.submit(runnable);
    }
}
```

**Reader.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Reader {
    private final BufferedReader br;

    public Reader(final String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    }

    public String readLine() throws IOException {
        return br.readLine();
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Reader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Reader reader = new Reader("pipe");
        while(true) {
            try {
                String readLine = reader.readLine();
                System.out.println("readLine = " + readLine);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                reader.close();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want pipes to stay active and queue up messages, you probably want a messaging system rather than a raw pipe.  In Java, the standard API is called "Java Messaging System" ([JMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service)), and there are many standard implementations-- the most common of which I've seen being Apache [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/).  If you want a cross-platform, sockets-like interface that does buffering and recovery I might suggest [0MQ](http://www.zeromq.org/), which while not being "pure Java" has bindings for many languages and excellent performance.

Answer (score 2):

If there was such a thing as non-blocking file I/O in Java, which there isn't, a write to a named pipe that wasn't being read would return zero and not write anything. So non-blocking isn't part of the solution.

There's also the issue that named pipes have a finite buffer size. They aren't infinite queues regardless of whether there is a reading process or not. I agree with the suggestion to look into JMS.

Comment: There is non blocking file IO. search for NIO(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O)

Comment: The definitive reference for NIO and Java in general is not Wikipedia but the Javadoc, which doesn't say that. Neither does Wikipedia either for that matter. And NIO stands for 'New I/O', Wikipedia notwithstanding.

Comment: I know this is an old Q/A, but for sake of correctness it's worth pointing out that Java 7 has [AsynchronousFileChannel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html).

Comment: @nilskp For the sake of correctness, it is worth pointing out that asynchronous I/O is not the same thing as non-blocking I/O, and that an asynchronous write to a pipe that isn't being read would never terminate, which makes it not part of the solution either.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use NIO's asynch `write` on a UNIX FIFO, just as you can to any other file:

```
 AsynchronousFileChannel channel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(...);
 Future<Integer> writeFuture = channel.write(...);
```

... or...

```
 channel.write(..., myCompletionHandler);
```

However, it's not clear to me what you want to happen when the FIFO isn't accepting writes. Do you want it to buffer? If so you'll need to provide it within the Java program. Do you want it to time out? There's no simple timeout option on Java file writes.

These aren't insurmountable problems. If you're determined you can probably get something working. But I wonder whether you'd not find life much easier if you just used a TCP socket or a JMS queue.

Comment: If you check javadoc for AsynchronousFileChannel it states:"An AsynchronousFileChannel is associated with a thread pool ..." . So, this class doesnt really offer nonBlocking API, just async...

Comment: The main problem with using `AsynchronousFileChannel` on UNIX FIFOs is that the `write()` operation (and also `read()`) requires a write position, and then uses `seek()` on the file descriptor before writing - which is a big no-no for FIFOs.