# Read file line by line using non-blocking IO with reactive wrapper in Java

Tags: java, rx-java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, nonblocking

Is there any way to read a local file line by line **without blocking any thread (background thread pool counts as blocking)** using built-in CompletableFuture or a reactive stream library like RxJava or Reactor?

(It's interesting that there are many non-blocking IO libraries for HTTP and different databases like Mongo, Redis, etc., but I wasn't able to find anything for a simple file read.)

Comment: You can't. There is no non-blocking I/O on files in Java. There is however *asynchronous* I/O, via `AsynchronousFileChannel`, but it doesn't support reading lines. Why do you think you need this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are similar questions:

- [Why FileChannel in Java is not non-blocking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955250/why-filechannel-in-java-is-not-non-blocking)
- [Non-blocking file IO in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601586/non-blocking-file-io-in-java)

The main reason why Java has no universal non-blocking file IO is the following: Java is a cross-platform language, but Unix does not have non-blocking access to files.

If you program for Windows, there is a platform-specific implementation [WindowsAsynchronousFileChannelImpl](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/nio/ch/WindowsAsynchronousFileChannelImpl.java.html), that uses a non-blocking mechanism.

Comment: Not really sure where you came up with the "Linux/Unix does not have non-blocking file IO" part, You can use `AsynchronousFileChannel` on Linux as well and it has been there at least since JDK 8. As far as I know you should be good to go if you have a kernel 2.6+. Do you have any articles I can check regarding the non-blocking file IO you mentioned? :)

Answer (score 2):

Although, I got answer for my question from Alexander, I'd like to share the most reactive ways that I found to read a file line by line. Both solutions use `AsynchronousFileChannel` under the hood which is not always non-blocking but still okay to use in a reactive environment since it uses a dedicated thread pool for IO work.

## Using utils from Spring Framework (ideal in WebFlux application)

```java
import org.springframework.core.codec.StringDecoder;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferUtils;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DefaultDataBufferFactory;

import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousFileChannel;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

public class AsyncFileRead {
    public Flux<String> lines() {
        StringDecoder stringDecoder = StringDecoder.textPlainOnly();

        return DataBufferUtils.readAsynchronousFileChannel(() -> AsynchronousFileChannel.open(Path.of("test/sample.txt"),
                StandardOpenOption.READ), DefaultDataBufferFactory.sharedInstance, 4096)
            .transform(dataBufferFlux -> stringDecoder.decode(dataBufferFlux, null, null, null));
    }
}
```

## Using [RxIo](https://github.com/javasync/RxIo) library

```java
import org.javaync.io.AsyncFiles;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import java.nio.file.Path;

public class AsyncFileRead {
    public Flux<String> lines() {
        return Flux.from(AsyncFiles.lines(Path.of("test/sample.txt")));
    }
}
```