# Java Reactive Way to read lines of a File

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

So I started to play with the Advent of Code and I would like to use the project reactor for this to find the solutions in a reactive way.

I have implemented a solutions that works partially but not quite how I want it. Because it can also read lines partially if there is no more space in the buffer.

The Input to run the following function you can find here: https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/1/input

```
        public static Flux<String> getLocalInputForStackOverflow(String filePath) throws IOException {
    Path dayPath = Path.of(filePath);
    FileOutputStream resultDay = new FileOutputStream(basePath.resolve("result_day.txt").toFile());

    return DataBufferUtils
            .readAsynchronousFileChannel(
                    () -> AsynchronousFileChannel.open(dayPath),
                    new DefaultDataBufferFactory(),
                    64)
            .map(DataBuffer::asInputStream)
            .map(db -> {
                try {
                    resultDay.write(db.readAllBytes());
                    resultDay.write("\n".getBytes());
                    return db;
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            })
            .map(InputStreamReader::new)
            .map(is ->new BufferedReader(is).lines())
            .flatMap(Flux::fromStream);
}
```

The point of this function is to read the lines of the files in a reactive way.

I used the `FileOutputStream` to write what I read into another file and the compare the resulted file with the original, because I noticed that some lines are only partially read if there is no more space in the buffer. So the try-catch `.map()` can be ignored

My questions here would:

1. Is there a more optimal way to read files asynchronously in a Reactive way?
2. Is there a more optimal way to read a file asyncronously line by line with a limited buffer and make sure that only whole lines are read?

Workarounds that I've found are:

1. Increased the buffer to read the whole file in 1 run -> Not optimal solution
2. Use the following functions, but this raise a warning:
    `Possibly blocking call in non-blocking context could lead to thread starvation`

```
    public static Flux<String> getLocalInput1(int day ) throws IOException {
        Path dayPath = getFilePath(day);
        return Flux.using(() -> Files.lines(dayPath),
                Flux::fromStream,
                BaseStream::close);
    }
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71070490/6051176

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. Just use `BufferedReader` instead of `Files.lines`.

In Spring Webflux, the optimal way to read files asynchronously in a reactive way is to use the Reactor Core library's `Flux.using` method. It creates a Flux that consumes a resource, performs some operations on it, and then cleans up the resource when the Flux is complete.

Example of reading a file asynchronously and reactively:

```
Flux<String> flux = Flux.using(

                     // resource factory creates FileReader instance
    () -> new FileReader("/path/to/file.txt"),

                     // transformer function turns the FileReader into a Flux
    reader -> Flux.fromStream(new BufferedReader(reader).lines()),

                     // resource cleanup function closes the FileReader when the Flux is complete
    reader -> reader.close()
);
```

Subscribe to the Flux and consume the lines of the file as they are emitted; this will print each line of the file to the console as it is read from the file.

```
flux.subscribe(line -> System.out.println(line));
```

---

In similar way we can solve it controlling each line explicitly:

```
Flux<String> flux = Flux.generate( 

    () -> new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/path/to/file.txt")),

                 // generator function reads a line from the file and emits it
    (bufferedReader, sink) -> {
        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        if (line != null) {
            sink.next(line);
        } else {
            sink.complete();
        }
    },
   
    reader -> Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
       try {
         reader.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
          // Handle exception
       }
    })
);
```

Comment: Hi, your solutions looks good, but i receive for `reader -> reader.close()` a warning that is an unhandled exception. Then if I surround it with a try/catch there is another warning that the `reader.close()` is a possible blocking call in a non blocking operation.

Is there a way to optimise this behaviour?

Comment: Yes, for simplisity I did not include try-catch boilerplate. The "blocking call" warning can be avoided with `Mono.fromRunnable`. The answer is updated.